# $ 2^{\sqrt n} \leq |\operatorname{ tr}( A^n)| \leq 2020\cdot2^{\sqrt n} $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, trace, symmetric-matrices

I am trying to prove the following claim 
There does not exist an integer $r\geq1 $ and a symmetric matrix $ A \in M_r(\Bbb R) $ Such that for all $ n \in \Bbb N $ we have 
$$ 2^{\sqrt n} \leq |\operatorname{tr}( A^n)| \leq 2020\cdot2^{\sqrt n} $$
Please give me some idea how to start this problem?

Comment: Where it comes from ? What have you tried ? see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3758763/does-there-exist-a-symmetric-matrix-a-such-that-2-sqrtn-le-operatornam?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to prove it by contradiction using the fact that real symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues and are diagonalizable. Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_r$ be the real eigenvalues of the matrix $A$. Then $|tr(A^n)|=|\lambda_1^n+\lambda_2^n+\cdots+\lambda_r^n|$.

Dividing both sides of your equation by $2^\sqrt{n}$. We get,
\begin{align*}
1\leq \biggl|{\sum_{i=1}^{r} \frac{\lambda_i^n}{2^\sqrt{n}}}\biggr| \leq2020
\end{align*}
Call the middle expression $S_n$

$\mathbf{Case 1}$: When $|\lambda_i| \leq 1 \: \forall i=1,2,\cdots, r$. Then taking limit $ n \rightarrow \infty $ in the above inequality we get $1\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}S_n = 0$. A contradiction

$\mathbf{Case 2}$: When at least one $|\lambda_i| > 1$. Wlog assume that to be $\lambda_1$. Then taking limit $n\rightarrow \infty$ in the above inequality we get $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}S_{2n} = +\infty \leq 2020$. Again a contradiction

$\mathbf{Edit}$: As pointed out in the comments the cases should be split accordingly whether $\lambda_i \geq 1$ and $\lambda_i < 1$.

Comment: @Marktmeister yes you are right. Thanks for pointing out. I'll edit my answer.